# How remove class when I resize screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need that on small devices (<992px) there was a class foot-active. And when we clicked on link "More" on large devices (>992px), class foot-active was not added as of now. I wrote function on resize, but it isn't work right. What's amiss?..................................................

```js
if (jQuery(window).width() < 992) {
  $(document).on('click', '.foot-title', function(e) {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('foot-items')) {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('foot-active');
    }
  });
}

jQuery(window).bind('resize', function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.foot-title', function(e) {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('foot-items')) {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('foot-active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ddd;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
}

.foot-active .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foot-menu foot-items">
  <div class="foot-title">
    <a href="#">More</a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-item">
      <a href="#"><span class="link">Lorem 1</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
      <a href="#"><span class="link">Lorem 1</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
      <a href="#"><span class="link">Lorem 1</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .b-menu -->
</div>

<div class="foot-menu">
  <div class="foot-title">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries Media queries are, what you are looking for. You could define the display behaviour depending on the device's attributes.

Comment: No, I need add class foot-active on small devices, but don't add on large devices. That isn't media queries.

Comment: What jQuery version are you using? `As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated.` http://api.jquery.com/bind/ . Use `.on()`.

Comment: @Dan Perhaps you overthink what you "need" and model the behaviour of your footer class accordingly ;)

Comment: You only have an `if < 992`. There is an `if > 992` missing.

Answer (score 2):

When amending the UI for different viewport sizes you should use CSS Media Queries, not JS. They perform much better and make your JS code much simpler and semantic, not to mention the fact that the UI will not be broken if a user disables JS in their browser.

To achieve what you need you can have your jQuery code *always* toggle the class. You can then set the CSS to allow the class to affect the UI through a Media Query, something like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.foot-title', function(e) {
  $(this).closest('.foot-menu').toggleClass('foot-active');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ddd;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .foot-active .menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foot-menu foot-items">
  <div class="foot-title">
    <a href="#">More</a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-item">
      <a href="#"><span class="link">Lorem 1</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
      <a href="#"><span class="link">Lorem 1</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
      <a href="#"><span class="link">Lorem 1</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="foot-menu">
  <div class="foot-title">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Class .foot-active added on lagre screen (>992px). I need on large devices (>992px), class foot-active was not added/

Comment: It should make no difference. That's a UI concern and therefore down to CSS to action/ignore based on the media query currently being executed by the size of the viewport.